# Aura Attribute of Type Map is not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, map, aura-attribute

I have declared an auro Map attribute in my Lightning Component but when i try to set key value pair to the Map in CLient-Side Controller it throws null error.

COMPONENT CODE :

```
 <aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes>    
   <aura:attribute name="FilesNameMap" type="Map"/>
 </aura:component>
```

CLIENT_SIDE CONTROLLER CODE :

```
 onChangeFunction : function(component,event){

   var FilesNameMap = component.get("v.FilesNameMap");
       FilesNameMap['city']='bangalore';

}
```

Please suggest on how to use Map attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I believe this is a bug. If you do not default your Map to empty object `default="{}"`, then lightning appears to not register the existence of the `Map` declared in the markup.

So, the fix is simple - change your attribute definition to this:

```
<aura:attribute name="FilesNameMap" type="Map" default="{}"/>
```

---

**PREVIOUS**

You have a typo. 
In your attribute definition, you have called the `Map` `FilesNameMap` but in your getter you have called it `FilesObjectMap`.

Which means it's going to be null when you try to set something to it.